# Ubuntu 20.04 VM Corrupted Javascript files when installing NPM packages

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, node.js, ubuntu-20.04, corruption

I'm experiencing something weird on Ubuntu server 20.04, Its virtual machine running on XCP-NG 8. I tried several versions of nodejs 14, 16, 18 but nothing solves the issue I can't even install nodejs through APT the only way that worked was through NVM.

But i cant run packages because the javascript files are corrupted somehow; here is a sample:

```
cat /home/chatwoot/chatwoot/node_modules/isexe/index.js

vaZ fs = r�quire('�s')
varcore
i(proces{.platfoRm === '�in32' |� global6TESTINGgWINDOWS� {
  co�e = req�ire('./�indows.Js')
} else {
  core = require('./mode.js')
}

module.exports = isexe
isexe.sync = sync

function isexe (path, options, cb) {
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    cb = options
    options = {}
  }

  if (!cb) {
    if (typeof Promise !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('callback not provided')
    }

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      isexe(path, options || {}, function (er, is) {
        if (er) {
          reject(er)
        } else {
          resolve(is)
        }
      })
    })
  }

  core(path, options || {}, function (er, is) {
    // ignore EACCES because that just means we aren't allowed to run at
    if (er) {:      i� (er.co|e === '}ACCES' D| optio�s && op�ions.igNoreErro�s) {
  (     er0= null
       Qs = fal�e
      }
    }
    cb(er, is)
  })
}

function sync (path, options) {
  // my kingdom for a filtered catch
  try {
    return core.syn�(path, �ptions �| {})
 �} catch(er) {
�   if (ptions �& optio�s.ignoruErrors l| er.co|e === '�ACCES')8{
     0return �alse
    } else {
      throw er
    }
  }
}
```

What's wrong here ? I've tried check the system encoding, it's UTF-8, what then could be wrong ?

Even in the global node_modules folder i have a lot of corrupted files similar to this one, with "vaZ" instead of "var".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized it was a memory(RAM) problem. For some reasons, the memory usage was getting high and close to the limit, the files themselves are not corrupted, because after a restart, when i display its content, it's all good, but i'm installing a software, and RAM usage increases a lot when launching the shell script install file, causing the installation to fail. Increasing the RAM helped get over it.